# How to call main action from area view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

Structure of my project is:

MainProject (name of project)

Areas--->Admin (contains of Views , Controllers,..)

Controllers

Views

I have an area in my project.
Now i want to use main layout for a view of admin area,that main layout call some of actions.when my project is execute occur an error on line @Html.Action("Index", "Language" ) in main layout,that not find this view.

My code  of main layout is :

```
@using Constants
@using SquishIt.Framework

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDesc" />
  @RenderSection("SocialMeta", false)

 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div>
            @Html.Action("Index", "Language" )

    </div>
     .
     .  
   </div>
   </body>
```

and my code of view of admin area is :

```
@model AdminModerateViewModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "management";
   Layout = string.Concat("~/Views/Shared/", "_Layout", ".cshtml");
 }
 <div>
  ........
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.Action` provides an override that looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Action(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues
)
```

Notice the last argument: `routeValues`.

The `Html.Action` helper will use the current area if one isn't specified. So, when it is rendered in your "main" views, it will render: `/Language/Index`. When it is rendered in your admin views .. it will render: `/Admin/Language/Index` .. which may or may not exist.

What you want to do is override the area it uses .. so that it always uses the "main" area:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Language", new { area = "" }) @* Blank area .. "main" area *@
```